# Global variable use case

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I have a couple of scripts and modules that use global variables for a number of things. My logging can take one of three forms; Terse, Verbose and Validation (Verbose logging with no actual actions, just validation of provided data). I also have a number of functions that respond differently depending on the Context they are run in (User or Machine), and the Action being executed (Rollout, Remove, Conform, Relocate) impacts things as well.
So, thus far I have used three global variables and it has worked, but I know best practice is to avoid global variables. That said, the only way to address it seems to be some Get and Set functions in one module, and Script level variables. Which seems like it adds complexity without really addressing much, since I still have variables that are in a higher scope than the function using them. Alternatively I could pass those three values to every function that needs them, but that also is lots of arguments that add little value. So I start wondering, is this one place where global variables really are the correct answer? Their existence suggests there must be some situation where one should use them, and this is starting to feel like exactly that situation.

Comment: With global variables naming becomes a key factor.   What names have you given the three global variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Avoiding Global Variables in PowerShell using Dynamic Scoping

PowerShell implements [Dynamic Scoping](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicScoping).  This is a rare choice in language design these days, but properly applied dynamic scoping gives a developer much better control over name collisions than global variables.    To understand how this might apply to your case(s), lets consider the following toy module:

```
# File Module1.psm1

$module = "Module1"
$Context = "User"

function Log-Message( $message ) {
    Write-Host "$module/${action}: $message ($LogLevel-$Context)"
}

function CommonCode { 
    Log-Message "In CommonCode"
}


function Invoke-Rollout( $LogLevel = "Terse", $Context=$script:Context) { 
    $action = "Rollout"
    CommonCode  
}

function Invoke-Remove( $LogLevel = "Terse", $Context=$script:Context) {
    $action = "Remove"
    CommonCode
}

function Set-Module1( $Context=$script:Context ) {
    $script:Context = $Context
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-Rollout, Invoke-Remove, Set-Module1
```

What's important here is that in `Log-Message`, the variables `$module`, `$action`, `$LogLevel` and `$LogContext` are **not** *global variables*, instead they are *free variables* who's scope has not yet been determined.   At runtime, PowerShell will dynamically determine their binding based on the most recent definition in the call stack...

Rather than trying to explain this in detail, it may be best for you to play around with this toy module and see what the effect of dynamic scoping is on the logging. Here are some experiments I tried:

```
PS C:\temp> Import-Module -Force .\Module1.psm1

PS C:\temp> Invoke-Rollout
Module1/Rollout: In CommonCode (Terse-User)

PS C:\temp> # For Sticky Change -- Set-Module1
PS C:\temp> Set-Module1 -Context Machine

PS C:\temp> Invoke-Rollout
Module1/Rollout: In CommonCode (Terse-Machine)

PS C:\temp> Invoke-Remove -LogLevel Verbose -Context XXX
Module1/Remove: In CommonCode (Verbose-XXX)

PS C:\temp> Invoke-Remove -Context User
Module1/Remove: In CommonCode (Terse-User)

PS C:\temp> $Context = "FooBar" # This should have no effet on Module1

PS C:\temp> Invoke-Remove
Module1/Remove: In CommonCode (Terse-Machine)
```

Comment: thanks for the great demonstration of dynamic scoping!

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing wrong with using global variables in specific scenarios, particularly for global settings or singleton objects that are defined once and then used throughout the rest of your code without further modification. Key point is to avoid changing the variables.

What you should **not** use global variables for is for transporting state, i.e. changing values. If you change the value of global variables at different places in your code troubleshooting problems becomes a huge pain in the rear, because you're passing information outside of the regular "channels" (parameters, return values). If you need to modify a global variable somewhere else in your code it's practically always a sign that you should re-evaluate your architecture.

Comment: I think that is where things get sticky here, because that Action is sure to change. Maybe I need to look at addressing the action differently, and use a global constant for the rest. I am doing a big refactoring, so now is the time to rethink, thats for sure.
That said, does a pair of Set-Action & Get-Action functions address the issue, or is that really considered a variation on the same problem? Basically I would set the Action to Remove, loop through a bunch of tasks, set to Rollout, loop, set to Conform and loop.